# Cmake GUI could not find boost (missing: system python3) (found version "1.72.0"), on Windows 10

Tags: python, windows, opencv, boost, cmake

I am trying to install [PyOpenPose](https://github.com/FORTH-ModelBasedTracker/PyOpenPose) on Windows 10, using Cmake GUI. It requires OpenCV so I downloaded the prebuild OpenCV for Windows. Then I cmake the repository, import the OpenCV directory, everything is ok, until it required Boost. I downloaded the latest Boost version 1.72.0 and copy it to `C:\boost\boost_1_72_0`, since the installation manual tells me to do that to get CMake to detect the Boost. But its detection was like this:

[image]

By reading it I guessed Cmake has detected the Boost but it could not detect the python, the missing is `system python3` and the Boost 1.72.0 has been found. So I add a `DPYTHON_EXECUTABLE` and set its path to `C:\Users\abc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\python.exe` but the problem still remains.

Those `DBOOST_LIBRARYDIR` and `DBOOST_ROOT` were added by me. Cmake exports the same errors even without those arguments.

So that I am stuck here.

Comment: Does this library also require you to *build* Boost, not only download it? Did you *build* the Boost libraries for the compiler you are targeting?

Comment: I did not until read your comment. Now I built it but the error still remains. I built with its `bootstrap.bat` file.

Comment: The `bootstrap.bat` file initializes for the build, but does not actually build the libraries. Running `b2` or `bjam` will *build* the libraries, consider looking through [this](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_72_0/more/getting_started/windows.html#invoke-b2) documentation.

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention it, after executing `bootstrap.bat` the command prompt said that use `./b2` to build and I did type the `./b2` and wait until the command prompt said that the build has been successful. And the problem still remains. I also added `DBOOST_LIBRARYDIR` and `DBOOST_ROOT` and set them to the boost directory.

Comment: Be aware that simply running `./b2` is not always sufficient, but it is often necessary to specify *which* libraries to build by specifying the *exact* compiler, build architecture, and static vs shared libraries.